# Excel VBA - Copy a formula result to a cell in another sheet + add succesive formula results in consecutive rows each time the formula is recalculated

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am running a partially randomize set of data and trying to find the best solutions depending on certain parameter changes. I need to "record" certain solutions and then compare different results for different parameters each time the randomized variables are recalculated.

I would like to do the to following:

1. On Sheet1, cell S255, is the result of a formula =SUM(M252:S252)
2. I need to automatically add that result (Sheet1 S255), to Sheet5, column A, starting at A1.
3. Then, each time the formula is recalculated and the result changes, I need the new result to be added to the consecutive row to the previous result (so the second result would go to A2, third one to A3, and so on).

Looking for similar cases I have come to be able to do 1. and 2. using this event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet5") 'declare and set the worksheet the data is to be copied into, amend the sheet name as required
If Target.Address = "$S$255" Then 'if anything changes in C6 or C9 in this sheet
   ws.Range("A1").Value = Target.Parent.Range("S255") 'copy the value from cell C10 in this sheet to Sheet2 in cell E5
End If
End Sub
```

Doing 3. is proving more challenging. What event would be suitable to do so?

Thanks in advance for your time and understanding!

Comment: The `Worksheet.Calculate` event?

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you are able to solve it with the Worksheet_Calculate event like BigBen suggested. Under "Random numbers" are just a few numbers with the RANDBETWEEN-Function for showing puposes. Just change the code for your case. Everytime you press "Delete" for exaple the new sum will be set under the Results column.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim lastRow As Long

'EnableEvents must be switched off so that the macro does not
'call itself in an endless loop by cell change

Application.EnableEvents = False

    lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C")) + 1
    Range("C" & lastRow).Value = Range("A9").Value

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: example saving sum ONLY IF SUM CHANGES]

```
'example saving sum ONLY IF SUM CHANGES

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim offsetLastSum As Long, curSum As Double

   offsetLastSum = Range("NEXT_SUM_OFFSET").Value2
   curSum = Range("THE_SUM").Value2
   
   With Range("SUM_HISTORY_HEAD")
      If .Offset(offsetLastSum - 1).Value2 <> curSum Then
         Application.EnableEvents = False
         .Offset(offsetLastSum).Value2 = curSum
         Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
   End With
   
End Sub
```